# Magento Error - Reinstalled Live Database

Tags: magento-1.9

I had a error with a module, so I had to reinstall a copy of the Live database. But when I have installed it on the front end of the website I get a Magento error code, and I have checked it in the logs and it gave me:

```
a:5:{i:0;s:102:"Cannot send headers; headers already sent in /home/vhosts/dev/hershesons/htdocs/app/Mage.php, line 767";i:1;s:1085:"#0 /home/vhosts/dev/hershesons/htdocs/lib/Zend/Controller/Response/Abstract.php(115): Zend_Controller_Response_Abstract->canSendHeaders(true)
#1 /home/vhosts/dev/hershesons/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1246): Zend_Controller_Response_Abstract->setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html; char...')
#2 /home/vhosts/dev/hershesons/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(80): Mage_Core_Model_App->getResponse()
#3 /home/vhosts/dev/hershesons/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(202): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->getResponse()
#4 /home/vhosts/dev/hershesons/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#5 /home/vhosts/dev/hershesons/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#6 /home/vhosts/dev/hershesons/htdocs/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#7 /home/vhosts/dev/hershesons/htdocs/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#8 {main}";s:3:"url";s:1:"/";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:7:"default";}
```

Is there anyway around this, as I am looking at getting the site back up.

Answer (score 1):

It is not a "magento" error but a PHP. In magento, it mostly happen when you have a closing `?>` at the end of a php class file. It can happen in many other situations that you can check following this link :

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php

By the way, be aware that if you reinstall database but not remove the files of the module or turn it off, it reinstall at the first refresh of a page.